# Regex to remove only special characters and not other language letters

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-negation

I used a regex expression to remove special characters from name. The expression will remove all letters except English alphabets.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String name = "Özcan Sevim.";
    name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", " ").trim();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

**Output:**

```
zcan Sevim
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Özcan Sevim
```

I get bad result as I did it this way, the right way will be to remove special characters based on ASCII codes so that other letters will not be removed, can someone help me with a regex that would remove only special characters.

Comment: why not use a regex which includes all special characters? So instead of a whitelist, create a blacklist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\p{IsLatin}` or `\p{IsAlphabetic}`

```
name = name.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsLatin}]", " ").trim();
```

Or to remove the punctuation just use `\p{Punct}` like this :

```
name = name.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ").trim();
```

---

**Outputs**

```
Özcan Sevim
```

take a look at the full list of [Summary of regular-expression constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and use the one which can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Guava *CharMatcher* for that :) It  will be easier to read and maintain it.

```
name = CharMatcher.ASCII.negate().removeFrom(name);
```

Answer (score -1):

use [\W+] or "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" as regex to match any special characters and also use String.replaceAll(regex, String) to replace the spl charecter with an empty string. remember as the first arg of String.replaceAll is a regex you have to escape it with a backslash to treat em as a literal charcter.

```
 String string= "hjdg$h&jk8^i0ssh6";
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
        Matcher match= pt.matcher(string);
        while(match.find())
        {
            String s= match.group();
        string=string.replaceAll("\\"+s, "");
        }
        System.out.println(string);
```